# SNMP Exporter Not Displaying Correct Interface Details but when i use snmpwalk command it does

Tags: prometheus, snmp, prometheus-alertmanager, snmp-trap

My goal is to obtain metrics from the SNMP device, and I have successfully configured my snmp.yaml file. However, I would prefer to add numerous targets directly to Snmp.yaml rather than through the Prometheus configuration.

```
auths:
  public_v2:
    version: 3
    security_level: authPriv
    username: user
    password: passwd
    auth_protocol: SHA
    priv_protocol: AES
    priv_password: privpass
modules:
  if_mib:
    walk:
     - 1.3.6.1.2.1.2
     - 1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1
     - 1.3.6.1.4.1.2636.3.1.13
```

and the targets are 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.1.2 and main motive is to get the interface details.

i have tried in the browser by having the url like below,

```
http://10.10.101.9:9116/snmp?target=192.168.1.1&auth=public_v2&module=if_mib
```

Not the correct interface status is being produced. The identical metrics that I saw in one of the target IPs are being generated even when I attempt using the incorrect target IP (1.1.1.1), which theoretically shouldn't be showing any metrics at all.

Note: I have not pasted all the config of snmp.yml

I am expecting the same status from snmp_exporter, which is running as a docker, if I use the snmpwalk command. I have also pointed the correct configuration while running it, even though I am not receiving the correct interface data.

SNMP version: 0.25.0